# How to specify $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' in a one liner

Tags: linux, ssh, powershell, windows-server-2019

I'm running PowerShell commands through `ssh` from a Linux server  and I need to specify `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` in a one liner for an `Invoke-Request` command.

```
ssh it@1.2.3.4 PowerShell \$ProgressPreference='SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://example.com/archive.zip -OutFile archive.zip;
```

fails due to

```
SilentlyContinue : The term 'SilentlyContinue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:21
+ $ProgressPreference=SilentlyContinue
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SilentlyContinue:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried

- omitting the escaping of `$`
- various quotes `'`, `"` and `\"` and combinations thereof

resulting in very similar error messages stating that command or object can't be found.

I'm running OpenSSH on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter in Google Compute Platfrom VMs and connecting from the Google Cloud SDK Docker image 327.0.0 running on Google Kubernetes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally really don't like to fight with escaping stuff, so I'd simply go for this:

```
Set-Variable ProgressPreference SilentlyContinue ; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://example.com/archive.zip -OutFile archive.zip;
```

The [`Set-Variable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet assigns a value to a specified variable or changes the current value. If the variable does not exist, the cmdlet creates it.